# How optimize request with JPA and Join?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to optimize treatment for search request

I have a principal object Referentiel :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "referentiel")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Referentiel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false)
    private UUID uuid;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "reference", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String reference;

    ....

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reference")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("referentiels")
    private Set<ReferentielMetal> metaux = new HashSet<>();
```

And the Object "ReferentielMetal"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "referentiel_metal")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class ReferentielMetal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

....

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("referentielMetals")
    private Referentiel reference;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("referentielMetals")
    private Metal metal;
```

In my treatment, I do e request to get all Referentiel with criteria. Then I walk through each occurrence to complete the data

For each Referentiel object, for example, I search all ReferentielMetal with ReferentielId :

```
@Query("select referentiel_metal from ReferentielMetal referentiel_metal where referentiel_metal.reference.id = :referenceId")
List<ReferentielMetal> findAllByReferenceId(@Param("referenceId") Long referenceId);
```

In my log, I see the request :

```
select referentie0_.id as id1_89_, referentie0_.createur_id as createur6_89_, referentie0_.date_creation as date_cre2_89_, referentie0_.date_modification as date_mod3_89_, referentie0_.metal_id as metal_id7_89_, referentie0_.modificateur_id as modifica8_89_, referentie0_.poids as poids4_89_, referentie0_.principal as principa5_89_, referentie0_.reference_id as referenc9_89_ from referentiel_metal referentie0_ where referentie0_.reference_id=?
```

But right after, I see in the logs a request on the Referential table

```
select referentie0_.id as id1_89_, referentie0_.createur_id as createur6_89_, referentie0_.date_creation as date_cre2_89_, referentie0_.date_modification as date_mod3_89_, referentie0_.metal_id as metal_id7_89_, referentie0_.modificateur_ ...
from referentiel_digital referentie0_ 
left outer join jhi_user user1_ on referentie0_.createur_id=user1_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user2_ on referentie0_.modificateur_id=user2_.id 
left outer join referentiel referentie3_ on referentie0_.reference_id=referentie3_.id 
left outer join fournisseur_entite fournisseu4_ on referentie3_.code_fournisseur_id=fournisseu4_.id
left outer join jhi_user user5_ on fournisseu4_.createur_id=user5_.id 
left outer join entite entite6_ on fournisseu4_.entite_id=entite6_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user7_ on entite6_.createur_id=user7_.id 
left outer join entite entite8_ on entite6_.entite_mere_id=entite8_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user9_ on entite8_.modificateur_id=user9_.id 
left outer join type_entity typeentity10_ on entite8_.type_entity_id=typeentity10_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user11_ on fournisseu4_.modificateur_id=user11_.id 
left outer join fournisseur fournisseu12_ on fournisseu4_.referentiel_id=fournisseu12_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user13_ on fournisseu12_.createur_id=user13_.id 
left outer join four_edi_format_fichier fouredifor14_ on fournisseu12_.edi_format_fichier_id=fouredifor14_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user15_ on fouredifor14_.createur_id=user15_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user16_ on fouredifor14_.modificateur_id=user16_.id 
left outer join entite entite17_ on fournisseu12_.fabricant_id=entite17_.id 
left outer join four_methode_acces_photo fourmethod18_ on fournisseu12_.methode_acces_photo_id=fourmethod18_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user19_ on fourmethod18_.createur_id=user19_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user20_ on fourmethod18_.modificateur_id=user20_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user21_ on fournisseu12_.modificateur_id=user21_.id 
left outer join pays pays22_ on fournisseu12_.pays_id=pays22_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user23_ on referentie3_.createur_id=user23_.id 
left outer join entite entite24_ on referentie3_.entite_id=entite24_.id 
left outer join jhi_user user25_ on referentie3_.modificateur_id=user25_.id 
left outer join referentiel referentie26_ on referentie3_.reference_mere_id=referentie26_.id 
left outer join tva tva27_ on referentie26_.taxe1_id=tva27_.id 
left outer join tva tva28_ on referentie26_.taxe2_id=tva28_.id 
where referentie0_.reference_id=?
```

I don't understand why this request is launched... My treatment does not call this request. This request do left join on all @OneToMany fields of Referentiel

No request was done on @ManyToOne Metal metal

Have you an idea?

Comment: Either you are making a get call on a field that’s not fetched in Referential table or they are not lazy loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Default in JPA if you fetch a field that is joined between two table Jpa Fetch all related Data by running queries.

but If you want to cancel this Operation , you can do it by using   "lazy" parameter.
It Will fetch the Data once you request it.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: I try with @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("referentielMetals")
    private Referentiel reference; but result is the same